# Where can i put "str" ​or "inst" in the query?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a query:

```
cur.execute('SELECT X1 || ' - ' || X2 FROM SPL_PAYMENTS(?, ?, NULL, NULL)', (result1[0], result1[0]))
```

When I execute a query from the database, I get this error. I can not understand why:
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**

This  || '-' || I use to merge columns. It works fine without it. Help put "str" ​​or "inst" in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try escaping your single quote used for `'-'` Something like:

```
cur.execute('SELECT X1 || \' - \' || X2 FROM SPL_PAYMENTS(?, ?, NULL, NULL)', (result1[0], result1[0]))
```